# Toolbar items colors

Tags: android, material-design

I am using Toolbar class from in every `Activity` of my application.
I have two versions of Toolbar layout, but they differ only in TextView and EditText, wrapped in RelativeLayout.
Here is code of toolbar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar"
android:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar.LightPopup"/>
```

I played a lot with `android:theme` and `android:popupTheme` attributes, but often get the same result (shown below) and never what I needed.

In AndroidManifest.xml all activities use `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`

Finally, my `v21\styles.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Toolbar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">?android:attr/colorPrimary</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Toolbar.LightPopup"parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:background">@color/material_grey_200</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.TextAppearance.ExtraLarge" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large">
    <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
</style>
```

Here is what I get most of the time:
[image: Toolbar menu]
[image: Toolbar item hint]
Note blue background of text.

---

In contrast, how it looks in Youtube app (and in many other apps, not only from Google)
[image: Youtube toolbar menu]
[image: Youtube toolbar item hint]

---

I want at least to make background of hints consistent (preferably grey).
If possible, I want also to control color of popup Toolbar menu.
I tried several solutions in SO (especially playing with styles) and on my own, but nothing helped.
If you have any idea how to fix it, please share it with me.
Thanks in advance.

**UPD:** As no one except me answered to the question, I accept my answer as best because it is really helped me. Hovewer, if you have some additions and clarifications, feel free to share. For example, I still don't know why changing `android:theme` to `style` fixed everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally came up with solution by myself.
Turns out it takes two steps to fix my Toolbar layout.
1) In Toolbar xml layout:

- Delete last attribute
- Replace `android:theme` by `style`

This results in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    style="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar"/>
```

2) In `styles.xml` file, add next items to Toolbar style:

- `<item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>` (this will set popup just like in Youtube app above)
- `<item name="theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>` (this will set title and other toolbar elements white)

Also remove Toolbar Popup style.
This result in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Toolbar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">?android:attr/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
        <item name="theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.TextAppearance.ExtraLarge" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large">
        <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I hope this will help someone as it helped me.